# How do I return a unique random row from a table in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, random

model

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
def self.energy(v, w)
  a = self.where('energy_id = ? AND weight = ?', v, w)
  a.offset(rand(a.count)).first.name
end
```

view

```
<%= form_for(@answer) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit "#{Answer.energy(3, 1)}", name: "answer", class: "btn" %>
  <%= f.submit "#{Answer.energy(4, 1)}", name: "answer", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

I have that, and it returns a random value, properly.  I'm calling this 36 times though (18 pairs of 2), and I don't want the same value returned more than once, ever.  I tried all kinds of `.pop` variations, but failed every time.

Thanks for the help!

FOR THE CALL, I'm using these form buttons, so I went with:

```
<% names = [] %>

<div id='one' class='center'>
  <%= form_for(@answer) do |f| %>
    <%= f.submit "#{record = Answer.energy(3, 1, names)}", name: "answer", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% names << record %>
    <%= f.submit "#{record = Answer.energy(4, 1, names)}", name: "answer", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% names << record %>
  <% end %>
</div>
~~ 17 more times ~~
```

works like a charm!  Thanks, [jvnill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337166/jvnill), for the help!

Comment: Do you call the method `energy` 16 times, or you just want 16 unique rows?

Comment: What ORM are you using? ActiveRecord?

Comment: yes.  ActiveRecord::Base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can user `.order("RAND()")` for mysql and `.order("RANDOM()")` for postgre.

UPDATE: no duplicates.

```
def self.energy(v, w)
  where('energy_id = ? AND weight = ?', v, w).limit(16).uniq.pluck(:name)
end
```

UPDATE: 16 times, no duplicate

this returns the first random record that matches the energy and weight and is not included in except_names

```
# model
def self.energy(v, w, except_names = [])
  klass = where('energy_id = ? AND weight = ?', v, w)
  klass = klass.where('name NOT IN (?)', except_names) if except_names.any?
  klass.order('RAND()').first.name
end
```

this calls the method 16 times, each time adding a uniq name to names

```
# how to call
names = []
16.times do
  if record = Model.energe(1, 1, names)
    names << record
  end
end
```

Comment: I know how to get them in random order.  The `rand()` command up top works to get a random set.  What I'm after is to not get a duplicate once a row is given.  I want it to work like the `.pop` method, basically.  return the value, then remove it from the hash.

Comment: nope.  sounded good, but no dice.  what you have there returns the whole hash of results.  the `.pluck(:name)` says to explicitly only show the name column of the hash, which is a nice way of doing it.  but i get 9 results for each call (instead of one)

Comment: updated again. i thought you just wanted a list of 16 unique names.  the updated answer calls the method 16 times

Comment: except for the `record.name`, you totally nailed it!  The function returns the name, so no need.  Thank you so much!

Comment: nope. totally different. you're getting the ids from a list of names which isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

```
def self.energy(v, w)
  c = []
  a = self.where('energy_id = ? AND weight = ?', v, w)
  b = a.offset(rand(a.count)).first.name
  unless c.include?(b) do
    puts b
    c << b
    end
end
```

Comment: this results in a bunch of empty results.  it does look like you're on to something, though.  return b, then include b into c... then next time it's called, c will have some stuff in it, and not get included in the return.

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling it 16 times can you pass the already available rows as argument? if yes than would this work?

```
def self.energy(v, w, records = [])
  a = self.where("energy_id = ? AND weight = ? AND id NOT IN ('-1',?)", v, w, Array(records).map(&:to_param))
  a.offset(rand(a.count)).first.name
end
```

Usage:

```
records = []
16.times do
 records << Answer.energy(10, 5, records)
end
```

you can also pass single record instead of array:

```
other_record = Answer.energy(10,5)
Answer.energy(10, 5, other_record)
```

Comment: You need to track the records that you already fetched and pass them in your SQL query so it does not fetch it. You can build a helper or a presenter class to make tracking easier.